# how to bind a value of datasource to a checkbox in datalist with Eval()

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, datalist

I have a datalist in my asp.net page. I bind a datasource to it in codebehind
and I have a checkbox in this datalist.

```
 var n = from gi in DataContext.Context.GalleryImages
                join g in DataContext.Context.Galleries
                on gi.GalleryID equals g.GalleryID
                where g.UserID == UserID && gi.GalleryID==GalleryID
                select new
                {
                    GalleryID = g.GalleryID,
                    ImageDescription = gi.ImageDescription,
                    GalleryName = g.GalleryName,
                    ImageFileName = gi.ImageFileName,
                    IsAlbumImage = gi.IsAlbumImage,
                    ImageID=gi.ImageID
                };

        dlGalleryList.DataSource = n;
        dlGalleryList.DataBind();
```

When the "IsAlbumImage " is true the checkbox should be checked.
How can I bind this property to the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

It should be bind like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"  Checked='<%#Eval("IsAlbumImage") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to ways to bind checkbox in a datalist
1- (recommended) Binding it directly from the ASP code using the Bind or Eval

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"  Checked='<%#Eval("IsAlbumImage") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

2- Binding it on the ItemDataBound Event

First you will add the event handler to your datalist control, and adds the Boolean value to a datakey to be used in itemdatabound event

```
<asp:DataList ID = "DataList1"  OnItemDataBound="DataListItemEventHandler"  DataKeys = "IsAlbumImage"/>
```

Then you add the C# code that bind this

```
protected void DataListItemEventHandler(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
CheckBox checkbx = new CheckBox();
checkbx = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
checkbx.Checked = (bool) DataList1.DataKeys(e.Item.ItemIndex)("IsAlbumImage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox
    ID="check"
    runat="server"
    Checked='<%# Eval("column_name").ToString().Equals("1") %>'
    />
```